# Adding rows that are in the same quarter of dates

Tags: python, date, if-statement, conditional-statements, rows

I am currently working on python to add rows quarter by quarter.
The dataframe that I'm working with looks like below:

```
df = [['A','2021-03',1,9,17,25], ['A','2021-06',2,10,18,26], ['A','2021-09',3,11,19,27], ['A','2021-12',4,12,20,28],
         ['B','2021-03',5,13,21,29], ['B','2021-06',6,14,22,30], ['B','2022-03',7,15,23,31], ['B','2022-06',8,16,24,32]]
df_fin = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=['ID','Date','Value_1','Value_2','Value_3','Value_4'])
```

The Dataframe has 'ID', 'Date' column and three columns that are subjected for summation.

The 'Date' is in the form of 20XX-03, 20XX-06, 20XX-09, 20XX-12.
Within the same 'ID' value, I want to add the rows to make it to biannual dates. In other words, I want to add March with June, and add September with December

The final df will look like below:

| ID | Date | Value_1 | Value_2 | Value_3 | Value_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2021-06 | 3 | 19 | 35 | 51 |
| A | 2021-12 | 7 | 23 | 39 | 55 |
| B | 2021-06 | 11 | 26 | 42 | 59 |
| B | 2022-06 | 15 | 31 | 47 | 63 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `groupby`

```py
df_fin['temp'] = df_fin['Date'].replace({'-03': '-06', '-09':'-12'}, regex=True)
df_fin.groupby(['ID', 'temp']).sum().reset_index().rename(columns={'temp': 'Date'})
```

```
    ID  Date    Value_1 Value_2 Value_3 Value_4
0   A   2021-06 3   19  35  51
1   A   2021-12 7   23  39  55
2   B   2021-06 11  27  43  59
3   B   2022-12 15  31  47  63
```